# Update table with random numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

I need to update my table with random numbers, this is my table:

```
chr pos ref alt id_disease
chr1 123 A   A     NULL
chr2 456 A   T     NULL
```

I want to update the disease column with random numbers from 1 to 30000079.

To obtain this:

```
chr pos ref alt id_disease
chr1 123 A   A     5024
chr2 456 A   T     300045
```

Is there some random functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [RANDOM()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-math.html):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET id_disease = FLOOR(RANDOM() * 30000079) + 1
```

**Explanation**

Postgres' `RANDOM()` function returns a number in the range `0.0 <= x < 1.0`.  In the query above, this means that the *smallest* value would occur when `RANDOM()` returns `0`, giving `1` as the value.  The *highest* value would occur when `RANDOM()` returns something like `0.999999`, which would give a value slightly below `30000079`.  The `FLOOR` function would take it down to `30000078`, but then we add `1` to it to bring it back to `30000079`, your highest value.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the issue that all rows were updated with the same value. This happened because the random statement is only run once. I had to generate the random numbers in a temporary table first, and update the actual table after that:

```
WITH r AS (SELECT id, floor(random() * 30000079) AS rnd FROM table_name)
UPDATE table_name AS t
SET column_name = r.rnd
FROM r WHERE r.id = t.id;
```

Comment: Yep that's an another way to do it, i tried but in my case RANDOM() has updated well my table.